# If $A - B \succ 0$, is $AB^{-1} -I \succeq 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, hermitian-matrices

Let matrices $A, B \in \Bbb C^{n \times n}$ be Hermitian, and $A - B \succeq 0$. Is $A B^{-1} - I \succeq 0$? If so, why?

What about the positive definite case? ($A - B \succ 0$)

Comment: Is $A B^{-1}$ symmetric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not true. I'm assuming $A -B \succeq 0$ means $A-B$ is Hermitian positive semi-definite (and definite for $A-B \succ 0)$. Take $A=I_2$,
$B=\begin{pmatrix}
0.5 & 0 \\\\
0  & -2
\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Or, based on your answer: $ 1 - (-2) >0$, but $-1/2 -1 <0$.